# JSON ajax post data - get 400 bad request message

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

*First of all. I read many questions about this problem here in stackoverflow but nothing helps me.*

I've this function:

```
function ip_login(){
    //alert(JSON.stringify(arr_login));
    $.ajax({
        crossdomain: true,
        url: 'https://****/Token',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(arr_login),   
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) { 
            console.log(data);
        }
    });        
}
```

And this is my JSON string:

```
{"grant_type":"password","username":"mail@mail.de","password":"blabla"}
```

**With the google chrome extension 'postman' it works fine!**

If I test my code above I got the popular `400 bad request` message.

When I take the code of the extension 'postman' it doesn't work too.

This is the code of postman:

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://*****/Token",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  "data": {
    "grant_type": "password",
    "username": "mail@mail.de",
    "password": "blabla"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

I can't fine my issue..

I searched on Google and SO but no reply helped me.

Edit:

This is in my console:

**"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - https://awesome-url.de/Token"**

Comment: You're sending JSON, so use `application/json` instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` - assuming that the receiving API accepts JSON. If not, keep `form-urlencoded`, and provide an object to `data` instead of a JSON string. This is assuming that the receiving domain uses CORS, and you're not being blocked by the Same Origin Policy. Check the exact response of the request in the console to see the error message as well as the status code.

Comment: `dataType: 'json',` remove this line and try again.

Comment: You post data on same domain ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan CORS isn't the problem. There is a wildcard for all domains.

Comment: @Justcode nope - that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Trace both attempts in your F12 network tools and compare them byte-by-byte. Exporting as HAR and comparing with your favorite diff tool might help too. Any chance to have a look at the logs of awesome-url.de ?

Comment: @AlexanderKante your Oauth provider needs form-urlencoded values and you are sending json to it.

Comment: I think the problem is stringifiing JSON, can you do `data: arr_login`

Comment: @ManasovDaniel Thank you! It works!!! But why? :/

Comment: @AlexanderKante posted like an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in stringifiing JSON. Server expects json but you send string(stringified JSON). Try

```
function ip_login(){
    //alert(JSON.stringify(arr_login));
    $.ajax({
        crossdomain: true,
        url: 'https://****/Token',
        type: 'POST',
        data: arr_login,   
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) { 
            console.log(data);
        }
    });        
}
```

Comment: This works, but I can't get a response.. I should get a token.

Comment: what are you getting now?

Comment: Nothing. In my network tool the response tab is empty.

Comment: Nothing with status 200? Do you have access to serverside code?

Comment: Yes. Status 200.. No I don't have access to servcerside code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99794/discussion-between-manasov-daniel-and-alexander-kante).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but try anyways.
When I'm sending Json, I didn't use "JSON.stringify(arr_login)"
All I did was something like "data:{arr_login:arr_login}"

This is how my variable looks like.

```
var req = new Object();
req["type"] = 'refresh';
req["time"] = window.page_ordertime;
```

This is how my ajax looks like

```
$.ajax( {
    url:"listorder_process.php",
    method: "POST",
    dataType:"json",
    data:{request:req}
} )
```